# Override Proxy Settings of Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, proxy

I'm working on win form application that uses different proxy IP's

I use this code to change them :

```
var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", true);
key.SetValue("ProxyServer", serverName + ":" + port);
key.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
```

It works fine with the first one only, but with the second usage to use a new proxy IP

It still sticks to the first one!

If I restarted my application, as previous, changing works only once and stick to it!

Are there any more modifications I need to do? Or am I missing something ?

Edit : i use these settings to navigate through a web browser control included in the form ..

Comment: What are you then doing with these settings?  Do you launch a web browser in your app?  Is there some way for you to use your own proxy settings without touching IE's?

Comment: yes i use these settings to navigate in a web browser control included in my application